# how can I use access_token get this [SCSoundCloud account]

Tags: ios, soundcloud

ios code

I log in through soundcloud login page, access to a access_token, how can I use access_token get this [SCSoundCloud account], any tips, appreciate it

Comment: When you say you have an "`access_token`", do you mean a `Client ID` and `Client Secret`? This seems to be what is necessary [for authentication](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#authentication). Also, what have you already tried (with code, if possible)?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have solved this problem. For this question I want is to delete the user track: 
code 
  By post 
  NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/%@.json?oauth_token=%", track_id, access_token];